# Simulate Long press by Touch events

Tags: android, event-handling, touch-event, long-press

How can we simulate long press by touch event? or how can we calculate the time that screen is touched, all in ACTION_DOWN state?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have implemented a Touch screen long click finally , thx all:

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    private static final int MIN_CLICK_DURATION = 1000;
    private long startClickTime;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            longClickActive = false;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (longClickActive == false) {
                longClickActive = true;
                startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (longClickActive == true) {
                long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                if (clickDuration >= MIN_CLICK_DURATION) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LONG PRESSED!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    longClickActive = false;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

in which `private boolean longClickActive = false;` is a class variable.

Comment: Thanks this lead to a solution for me.

Comment: the problem is long tap is waiting for ACTION_MOVE which sometimes is not called but the long tap must be captured

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You don't need to find hack for this.

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
 public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
  Log.e("", "Longpress detected");
 }
});

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
 if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
  return true;
 }
 switch (event.getAction()) {
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
   break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
   break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
   break;
 }
 return true;
}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

For calculating touch count you can get getPointerCount() of your event like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470174/in-android-how-to-get-how-much-of-a-finger-touched-the-screen)

and for Long click maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324362/detect-touch-press-vs-long-press-vs-movement) helps

**Edit**: and hope [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278579/android-touch-event-determining-duration/7121688#7121688) help you determining getting touch duration

Comment: I need time not count dude.

Comment: maybe i couldn't understand you well , so hope edited answer and attached link help you more , good luck

Comment: It was not completely my answer but inspired me by using Boolean flags. thx :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to count time between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP events.
It's impossible to calculate this time only in ACTOIN_DOWN state, cause it's the START event of sequence of events  representing TAP of LONG TAP event

Comment: Thx , I did it by using ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE.