# In android, onlongclick is not calling after ontouchevent

Tags: android, android-view

I have created a new `view` called RecorderView and inside this class there is an onTouchEvent() like below,

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (isRecording) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Log.d("JM", "ACTION_DOWN");
                return false;
            }

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Log.d("JM", "ACTION_UP");
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                stopRecord();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Then this view is inflated in a listview by extending BaseAdapter and there it has a setOnLongClickListener() inside getView() like below

```
holder.recordView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Log.d("JM", "On list item clicked");
                holder.recordView.startRecord();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

and now the problem is setOnLongClickListener() is not executing.

I am trying to sort it out for the last 2 days. But still not solved.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `OnItemLongClick` to achieve what you want? I believe you want every item of the ListView to respond to `OnLongClick`, right?

Comment: OnItemLongClick is calling but now MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is not getting

Comment: @JMIndia You have to return `true` in your `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` so that `MOTIONEVENT.ACTION_UP` will be handled, otherwise control is not returned to the application and execution ends at `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` event. You can test this by writing out some string to the console both for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

Comment: Hi i tried that too. But at that time OnItemLongClick is not calling :(

Answer (score 0):

When you override onTouchEvent for any view, then longpressed is consumed by onTouchEvent only. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896168/simulate-long-press-by-touch-events) is one useful post, using solution mentioned you can implement long press using onTouchEvent.

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    private static final int MIN_CLICK_DURATION = 1000;
    private long startClickTime;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            longClickActive = false;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (longClickActive == false) {
                longClickActive = true;
                startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (longClickActive == true) {
                long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                if (clickDuration >= MIN_CLICK_DURATION) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LONG PRESSED!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    longClickActive = false;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

in which private boolean longClickActive = false; is a class variable.